# How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry in ubuntu server?

Tags: installation, apt, updates

I am getting **Duplicate sources.list entry** exception every time i perform an update or install operation on my **Ubuntu server**.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://debian.datastax.com/community/
stable/main amd64 Packages
(/var/lib/apt/lists/debian.datastax.com_community_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://debian.datastax.com/community/
stable/main i386 Packages
(/var/lib/apt/lists/debian.datastax.com_community_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I am seen some similar posts over internet, still unable to resolve that.

Here is my `sources.list` content

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main
restricted deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main
restricted deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates
main restricted deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/
quantal-updates main restricted deb
http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe deb-src
http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe deb
http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe deb-src
http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe deb
http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted
universe multiverse deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/
quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse deb
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main
restricted deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security
universe deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security
universe deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security
multiverse deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security
multiverse
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But as i have said in my question i have seen some similar posts over net, unfortunately unable to resolve it

Comment: Upload your /etc/apt/sources.list and all files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ to http://paste.ubuntu.com and include their links in your question.

Comment: thanks for the response. And thankfully i am able figure out the issue... i have same contents in /etc/sources.list.d/ multiple files